# sudden disconnection after succesful connection to Mosquitto broker using Paho MQTT Js

Tags: javascript, ssl, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

I've managed to connect to my Mosquitto broker using a 1.1.0 version of Paho MQTT JS client. However, the client disconnects inmediately after completing the connection. Before using this version, I was using 1.0.1 and it worked. This is my code for the main functions involved:

```
function onConnectionLost(){
        console.log("connection lost");
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Connection Lost";
        connected_flag=0;
    }

    function onFailure(message) {
        console.log("Failed");
        setTimeout(MQTTconnect, reconnectTimeout);
    }
function onConnect() {
        connected_flag=1;
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Connected";
        console.log("on Connect "+connected_flag);
        sub_topics();

    }

    function MQTTconnect(id) {
        var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
        var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
        //mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client(host,port,id);
        mqtt = new Paho.Client("wss://192.168.1.42:9873/mqtt",id);
        //document.write("connecting to "+ host);
        var options = {
            timeout: 3,
            useSSL: true,
            userName: user,
            password: pass,
            onSuccess: onConnect,
            onFailure: onFailure,

        };

        mqtt.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
        mqtt.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
        mqtt.onConnected = onConnected;

        mqtt.connect(options);
        return false;


    }

    function sub_topics(){

        mqtt.subscribe("es2a2/rad");
        mqtt.subscribe("e12r/temp");
        mqtt.subscribe("e92/hum");


        return false;
    }
```

The log on the Mosquitto broker:

```
1588334688: New client connected from 192.168.1.43 as 33c1olvtc78311srsavrgq53ce (p2, c1, k60, u'admin').
1588334689: Socket error on client mgqilf3dv8dktthb7u4mudlm5i, disconnecting.
```

**EDIT 1**

Mosquitto.conf (using Mosquitto version 1.6.8):

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

per_listener_settings true

listener 9873
protocol websockets
cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwdfile

listener 8883
cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
```

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61542997/edit) to include your `mosquitto.conf` so we can see how it's setup for the websocket listener. Also include the mosquitto version information

Answer (score 0):

Socket errors right after a "Connect" message are almost always an Auth issue -- your password is wrong, you userID is wrong, you SSL cert is not known to Mosquitto, etc.  Double check all that and see if you find something.